# How do I evaluate this limit (without the use of L'Hospital or series expansions)?

Tags: limits, analysis, limits-without-lhopital

I have been trying for quite some time to evaluate this limit

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\tan x-\sin x}{x-\sin x}$$

but without using L'Hospital's rule or series expansions. I have tried the common things, I have got this:

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x(1-\cos x)}{\cos x(x-\sin x)}$$

But I have no idea how to proceed further.

Comment: Not even Taylor-Young's formula?

Comment: No, it we haven't even mentioned it yet.

Comment: What are you **assumed** to know?

Comment: try to expand sin and cos in series form then try

Comment: Trigonometric identities and the well-known limit(x->0)(sinx/x)=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Here the key limit will be derived. The rest should be easy.

Let:
$$
L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}.
$$ 
We have:
$$
L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x-\sin 2x}{8x^3}\implies
4L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\frac12\sin 2x}{x^3}\\\implies
3L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-\frac12\sin 2x}{x^3}
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x(1-\cos x)}{x^3}
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^3 x}{x^3(1+\cos x)}=\frac12\\
\implies L=\frac16.
$$

Comment: Thank you, this is brilliant, but how the hell can I figure this out myself?

Comment: @Matthew I do not know. How did you come to the idea to try this limit without series expansion?

Comment: We haven't yet covered series expansions and it was given as a starred exercise in our textbook (Felda & Klanjšček: Matematika 4, zbirka nalog za gimnazije).

Comment: @Matthew If you know the answer expected by the authors please let me know. :)

Comment: I think you had to do what you did, since I don't see any other way myself and I also get the right solution: 3. But I still don't think I could do what you did myself, but maybe I'll get better with practice. Thanks again for this wonderful solution!

Comment: @Matthew You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

We will be using $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\sin z}{z}=1$ frequently.
$$L=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{\cos x} \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{2}\sin^2(x/2)}{(x/2)^2} \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^3}{x-\sin x} =L/2~~~~(1)$$
Let $L=\frac{1}{A}$, where $$A=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{3x-\sin 3x}{(3x)^3}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{3x -3\sin x +4 \sin^3 x}{27x^3}.$$
$$\implies A=A/9+\frac{4}{27} \implies \frac{8A}{9}=\frac{4}{27} \implies A=\frac{1}{6}~~~~(2).$$ Using (2) in (1) we get the required limit $L=3.$